# Access the dp of a instagram account and show it dynamically in instagram story

Tags: dynamic, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-story

Ok so i have no idea how this guy did this or is there a possible explanation to this but ill link to his IG [account](https://www.instagram.com/stories/highlights/18019935175278450/) just check the story highlights and make sure that you're in a mobile. What it does is , it takes ur instagram dp and shows it as the most useless person, its fun but a cool trick, im pretty sure he uses some kind of code cause i think its dynamically entered(the dp?) into the story? but does instagram support this? Is there a way to do this ? Pls suggest. Thanks in advance :)

URl - https://www.instagram.com/vishantprogrammer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new sticker called "comment sticker" that is already available in some countries like Indonesia and this sticker has the viewer dp on the left

Comment: Yes i found that out, thanks for letting me know the country . Welcome to SO :)